# What is the difference between the following sql queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table say Table1 which has column1,column2.column3

now I run a select query :

```
Select * from Table1
```

which returns all the rows.

Another query

```
Select * from Table1 where column1 like '%%'
```

also returns all the rows.
The first one is a simple regular sql select query. Why does the second one act similar to the first one?
Can anyone tell me?

Comment: the first query will return all rows, the second will return all rows where column1 isn't null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is only that in second one you have a filter that is not filtering anything.

The `LIKE` operator works by searching a text or part of a text from a field. The `%` is a wildcard that is used to replace a set of characters (any amount).

In your case the second query is returning all rows because your given filter `column1 like '%%'` is evaluating to everything.

It works like this.

Imagine that your field `column1` has these values

```
foo
bar
goo
boo
zar
```

So if you use `column1 like '%%'` you are saying to your database: **give me all rows that the text into that `column1` starts with anything (any times) and ends with anything**. So everything. It will also return all rows if you use `column1 like '%'`

But if you use `column1 like '%oo%'` it will give you as answer `foo, goo and boo` or if you use `column1 like '%r'` you will have `bar and zar`

Hope it helps you to understand.

Comment: but when I don't put any characters inside the double % isn't it supposed to be treated as blank or null ?

Comment: No, never. The wildcard replaces a set of characters, ANY characters, no matter how many times you use that wildcard it will evaluate to everything.

Comment: Read the bold text on my answer. It says exactly what it do.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the outcome to be? '%' is a wildcard in SQL, so you're basically saying this:

1) "Select all from table"
2) "Select all from table where column 1 is literally anything"

These are effectively the same since the latter part of the second query does not refine the conditions at all. It's kind of like saying:

1) "Select all from alphabet"
2) "Select all from alphabet where the entry is a letter"

It's going to produce the same results because you aren't adding a significantly refined condition to the statement.

Answer (score 0):

- Because column1 like %% didn't filter any rows in the data set of the
  table.
- To be brief % will match any number of characters in Column1.
- If you want to match % character you need to use escaped patterns  \%

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html